# Why is my navigation drawer is duplicating my items?

Tags: kivy, kivymd

I have created a Navigation Drawer within my screen and I am using MDTopAppBar to open the drawer, but when I run the code it duplicates my items in the drawer[image: display].

Here is my kv code:

```
<Content>:
    ScrollView:
        MDList:
            OneLineListItem:
                text: "A new day begins"

            OneLineListItem:
                text: "Show stats"

<MenuWindow>:
    name: "menu"
    Screen:
        MDTopAppBar:
            title: 'menu toolbar'
            pos_hint: {"top":1}
            left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state("open")]]

        MDNavigationDrawer:
            id: nav_drawer
            Content:
```